# Creating dummy columns with real values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dummy-data

I have a DF as shown below:

```
DF =
id  Result      
1   Li_In-AR-B
1   Li_In-AR-L
3   N
4   Lo_In-AR-U
5   Li_In-AR-U
6   Or_Ba-AR-B
6   Or_Ba-AR-L
7   N
```

Now I want to create new columns for every unique value in `Result` before the first "-". Every other value in the new column should be set to `N`.

```
DF =
id  Result        Li_In         Lo_In       Or_Ba
1   Li_In-AR-B    Li_In-AR-B    N           N
1   Li_In-AR-L    Li_In-AR-L    N           N      
3   N             N             N           N
4   Lo_In-AR-U    N             Lo_In-AR-U  N
5   Li_In-AR-U    Li_In-AR-U    N           N
6   Or_Ba-AR-B    N             N           Or_Ba-AR-B
6   Or_Ba-AR-L    N             N           Or_Ba-AR-L
7   N             N             N           N
```

I thought I could do this easily using `.get_dummies` but this only returns a binary value in each cell.

```
DF_dummy = DF.Result.str.get_dummies(sep='-')
DF = pd.concat([DF,DF_dummy ],axis=1)
```

Any ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create boolean `DataFrame` by [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html), remove column `N` and compare by `1`. Then create `DataFrame` with same columns like mask and repalce values by [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
m = DF['Result'].str.split('-', n=1).str[0].str.get_dummies().drop('N', axis=1) == 1
df1 = pd.concat([DF['Result']] * len(m.columns), axis=1, keys=m.columns)

df = DF.join(df1.where(m.values, 'N'))
print (df)
   id      Result       Li_In       Lo_In       Or_Ba
0   1  Li_In-AR-B  Li_In-AR-B           N           N
1   1  Li_In-AR-L  Li_In-AR-L           N           N
2   3           N           N           N           N
3   4  Lo_In-AR-U           N  Lo_In-AR-U           N
4   5  Li_In-AR-U  Li_In-AR-U           N           N
5   6  Or_Ba-AR-B           N           N  Or_Ba-AR-B
6   6  Or_Ba-AR-L           N           N  Or_Ba-AR-L
7   7           N           N           N           N
```

Comment: What should I change when I have a row like this "1: Li_In-AR-B, Or-Ba-AR-B"? I need both of those in a separate column.

Comment: @ThelMi Do you think `1: Li_In-AR-B, Or_Ba-AR-B`? `_` after `Or` ?

Comment: Also there is space after `,`  ?

Comment: @ThelMi - Hmmm, I create solution and unfortunately cannot be used old one. What do you think, is possible create new question with change `1   Li_In-AR-B` to `1 Li_In-AR-B, Or_Ba-AR-B` with changing expected output? In my opinion itis better like editing this question. Thanks.

Comment: Then I can add answer to new question.

Comment: Yeah I tried using your old solution to solve this new case but I couldn't change it so that I would actually help me. I'm going to create a new question right now.

Comment: @ThelMi sorry, I am offline, on phone only, so untested solution.